# Unable to add Authorization header while calling WCF service with basic authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, rest, basic-authentication

I am trying to call a WCF service deployed on IIS with basic authentication enabled, from j query as below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        contentType: "application/javascript",
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: true
                        },                            
                        processData:false,                
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic SUlTVTA5OkludDNyZkBjMw==')
                        },
                        data: { 'inputData': "{PatientID:'12',FromDateTime:'05/21/2013 1:28:15 PM',ToDateTime:'05/21/2013 1:28:15 PM',ResponseType:'json',CompressResponse:'false'}" },                        
                        url: "http://192.168.15.160/ClearVitalsRestAPI/ClearVitalsService/GetMedicationValues",             


                        success: function (jsonData) {
                            console.log(jsonData);
                        },
                        error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(request.responseText);
                            console.log(textStatus);
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
    });
```

I get a browser pop up instead requiring the credentials.The HTTP headers are like below.
Request

```
URL:http://192.168.15.160/ClearVitalsRestAPI/ClearVitalsService/GetMedicationValues?      
callback=jQuery19108195633634459227_1369313893163&[object%20Object]&_=1369313893164
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.15.160
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:1087/RestClient/Default.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko)   
Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
callback:jQuery19108195633634459227_1369313893163
[object Object]:
_:1369313893164
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept,Authorization,Authentication
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:6523
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 23 May 2013 12:58:13 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="192.168.15.160"`
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

This header was collected after i clicked cancel on the browser's log in pop up.

Please suggest.Thank You.

Comment: Just to isolate the problem, try using JSON instead of JSONP. You may have to change `dataType` and `contentType`. See if it still gives you the authentication popup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aziz.I tried your suggestion and changed datatype to json and content type to application/json. I got following error :  Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true. My global.asax has  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: Since you are making a cross domain call JSONP is the correct datatype. But you might consider your content type to be application/json rather than application/javascript

Comment: I have tried that too.No cross domain problem,but my request credentials are unable to win over the browser log in pop up.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to your issue or not: [JSONP doesn't work with basic authentication](http://kevinkuchta.com/_site/2012/01/basic-authentication-with-jsonp/)

Comment: Yes, they are correct . i was able to access the service by providing these credentials to the browser login pop up.Thing is Authorization header is only being added if i provide the credentials to the pop up.No idea why i can't add Authorization header to my ajax request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this issue by changing data type to json instead of jsonp.The reason was jsonp was not allowing my web client to add Authorization header to my request.I found this fact from some forum in stack overflow.

Comment: If you found out it on SO, please add link. It might help to resolve similiar issues.